# Is there a quintessential mobile User-Agent regexp pattern?

Tags: regex, mobile, user-agent

There are endless examples in the tubes of regexp patterns designed to detect mobile User-Agents, even quite a few in answers herein. Do you know of one that is perhaps most widely used and supported (updated, in perhaps a Git repository)? There tends to be a `It's dangerous to go alone! Take this.` version of everything, eventually (e.g. [browser reset CSS by Eric Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset), et al), so perhaps there is for this as well.

Comment: Where is this elusive repository that you mention?

Comment: Ha, what an unfortunate typo (curious posterity: see revision history)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[detectmobilebrowsers.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) provides this solution (for JS):

```
(function(a,b){if(/android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))window.location=b})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,'http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');
```

Um, yeah, complex.

If you want to use another language, just head to the site.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Based on the complexity of that regexp, I'd say it's a bit more thought out than what we're currently using (which is basically just a |-separated list of names).

Comment: Might not want to use them, because when I tried the PHP of detectmobilebrowsers.com its not detecting ipad as mobile... 
this is my useragent then, Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3

Comment: See http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/about - pads and tablets are not detected by design.

Comment: Note: this recommended website has not been updated since 2014, so this may no longer be the quintessential answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to share these few points.

1. Some servers have **$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']** as not set, so make sure to check if empty first
2. Readability is important to us, so we are using this instead of others complex regex. Just **add other devices** as you see fit.

Here is the code we use:

```
<?php
if(! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if( preg_match('@(iPad|iPod|iPhone|Android|BlackBerry|SymbianOS|SCH-M\d+|Opera Mini|Windows CE|Nokia|SonyEricsson|webOS|PalmOS)@', $useragent) ){
        header('Location: ./mobile/');
    }
}
?>
```