# How to detect responsive breakpoints of Twitter Bootstrap 3 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, dom-events

[Currently](http://twbs.github.io/bootstrap/css/#grid-media-queries), Twitter Bootstrap 3 have the following responsive breakpoints: 768px, 992px and 1200px, representing small, medium and large devices respectively.

How can I detect these breakpoints using JavaScript?

I would like to listen with JavaScript for all related events triggered when the screen change. And to be able to detect if the screen is for small, medium or large devices.

Is there something already done? What are your suggestions?

Comment: You can use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to detect when a `<div class="d-none d-?-block"></div>` changes visibility (insert your desired breakpoint). Those CSS classes are for Bootstrap 4... use whatever works in Bootstrap 3. Much more performant than listening to window resize event.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

**Edit: This library is now available through Bower and NPM. See github repo for details.**

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

- Live example: [CodePen](http://cdpn.io/ivECj)
- Latest version: [Github repository](https://github.com/maciej-gurban/responsive-bootstrap-toolkit)
- Don't like Bootstrap? Check: [Foundation demo](https://github.com/maciej-gurban/responsive-bootstrap-toolkit/blob/master/demos/foundation/main.js) and [Custom framework](https://github.com/maciej-gurban/responsive-bootstrap-toolkit/blob/master/demos/custom/main.js) demos
- Have a problem? [Open an issue](https://github.com/maciej-gurban/responsive-bootstrap-toolkit/issues/new)

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Here's a few things you can do using the latest version (Responsive Bootstrap Toolkit 2.5.0):

```
// Wrap everything in an IIFE
(function($, viewport){

    // Executes only in XS breakpoint
    if( viewport.is('xs') ) {
        // ...
    }

    // Executes in SM, MD and LG breakpoints
    if( viewport.is('>=sm') ) {
        // ...
    }

    // Executes in XS and SM breakpoints
    if( viewport.is('<md') ) {
        // ...
    }

    // Execute only after document has fully loaded
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if( viewport.is('xs') ) {
            // ...
        }
    });

    // Execute code each time window size changes
    $(window).resize(
        viewport.changed(function() {
            if( viewport.is('xs') ) {
                // ...
            }
        })
    ); 

})(jQuery, ResponsiveBootstrapToolkit);
```

As of version 2.3.0, you don't need the four `<div>` elements mentioned below.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I don't think you need any huge script or library for that. It's a fairly simple task.

Insert the following elements just before `</body>`:

```
<div class="device-xs visible-xs"></div>
<div class="device-sm visible-sm"></div>
<div class="device-md visible-md"></div>
<div class="device-lg visible-lg"></div>
```

These 4 divs allow you check for currently active breakpoint. For an easy JS detection, use the following function:

```
function isBreakpoint( alias ) {
    return $('.device-' + alias).is(':visible');
}
```

Now to perform a certain action only on the smallest breakpoint you could use:

```
if( isBreakpoint('xs') ) {
    $('.someClass').css('property', 'value');
}
```

Detecting changes after DOM ready is also fairly simple. All you need is a lightweight window resize listener like this one:

```
var waitForFinalEvent = function () {
      var b = {};
      return function (c, d, a) {
        a || (a = "I am a banana!");
        b[a] && clearTimeout(b[a]);
        b[a] = setTimeout(c, d)
      }
    }();

var fullDateString = new Date();
```

Once you're equipped with it, you can start listening for changes and execute breakpoint-specific functions like so:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    waitForFinalEvent(function(){

        if( isBreakpoint('xs') ) {
            $('.someClass').css('property', 'value');
        }

    }, 300, fullDateString.getTime())
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. viewport.current() always yields 'unrecognized'. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle? Edit: Could it be that you include your scripts, including RBT in head section, instead of body? That would prevent visibility divs from being added to body, thus breaking the functionality.

Comment: @MaciejGurban I can't get it to work also. I'm using Rails 4.2. I'm including bootstrap in my head but your script in the body but it keeps saying unrecognised. Ok my problem I have added everything in the body. But is this really needed?

Comment: Once again, it's hard to tell the problem without a fiddle or sample code. You could ask a question about it on SO and reference it here, or open an issue on github. Have you followed the order of including all parts as it's on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/dih/full/ivECj)? Is only that function not working? Could the problem be like [this one](https://github.com/maciej-gurban/responsive-bootstrap-toolkit/pull/9)?

Comment: Do I have to install two third party package managers just to then use command line to download a JS file? I had never heard of Bower before today. Apparently it's a package manager that requires another package manager (npm). Why?

Comment: How could this be used with bootstrap 4?

Comment: @Calonthar you have to define custom breakpoints like the Custom demo

Answer (score 69):

If you don't have specific needs you can just do this:

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    // do something for small screens
}
else if ($(window).width() >= 768 &&  $(window).width() <= 992) {
    // do something for medium screens
}
else if ($(window).width() > 992 &&  $(window).width() <= 1200) {
    // do something for big screens
}
else  {
    // do something for huge screens
}
```

Edit: I don't see why you should use another js library when you can do this just with jQuery already included in your Bootstrap project.

Comment: Thanks, can you also provide the listener for all events that trigger on screen dimension change?

Comment: I don't think there are events on screen dimension change.
Everything related to screen dimension (media queries) is in the stylesheet.

Comment: I know that, I'm just looking a similar behavior in JS. Actually listen on screen dimension change with: `$(window).bind('resize')`... but there are other events related for mobile screen orientation that impact the screen dimension.

Comment: Device orientation is still an experimental feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent
I suggest you to use `.on('resize')`

Comment: I've heard of cases where this way of detecting state causes problems. It's better to go with something checking for visible helper elements imho - just to be safe from any corner cases.

Comment: The code pen doesn't work for me. Using chrome. Just wanted to let you know.

Comment: This doesn't work reliably on iOS devices. Both window and client widths give relatively random values after device rotation

Comment: Generally the most simple solution is the best solution. Thanks for the snippet! I was only looking for the width breakpoints.

Answer (score 15):

Here my own simple solution:

jQuery:

```
function getBootstrapBreakpoint(){
    var w = $(document).innerWidth();
    return (w < 768) ? 'xs' : ((w < 992) ? 'sm' : ((w < 1200) ? 'md' : 'lg'));
}
```

VanillaJS:

```
function getBootstrapBreakpoint(){
    var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    return (w < 768) ? 'xs' : ((w < 992) ? 'sm' : ((w < 1200) ? 'md' : 'lg'));
}
```

Answer (score 14):

### Detect responsive breakpoint of Twitter Bootstrap 4.1.x using JavaScript

The **Bootstrap v.4.0.0** (and the latest version **Bootstrap 4.1.x**) introduced the updated [grid options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options), so the old concept on detection may not directly be applied (see [the migration instructions](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#grid-system)):

- Added a new `sm` grid tier below `768px` for more granular control. We now have `xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`, and `xl`;
- `xs` grid classes have been modified to not require the infix.

I written the small utility function that respects an updated grid class names and a new grid tier:

```
/**
 * Detect the current active responsive breakpoint in Bootstrap
 * @returns {string}
 * @author farside {@link https://stackoverflow.com/users/4354249/farside}
 */
function getResponsiveBreakpoint() {
    var envs = {xs:"d-none", sm:"d-sm-none", md:"d-md-none", lg:"d-lg-none", xl:"d-xl-none"};
    var env = "";

    var $el = $("<div>");
    $el.appendTo($("body"));

    for (var i = Object.keys(envs).length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        env = Object.keys(envs)[i];
        $el.addClass(envs[env]);
        if ($el.is(":hidden")) {
            break; // env detected
        }
    }
    $el.remove();
    return env;
};
```

### Detect responsive breakpoint of Bootstrap v4-beta using JavaScript

The **Bootstrap v4-alpha** and **Bootstrap v4-beta** had different approach on grid breakpoints, so here's the legacy way of achieving the same:

```
/**
 * Detect and return the current active responsive breakpoint in Bootstrap
 * @returns {string}
 * @author farside {@link https://stackoverflow.com/users/4354249/farside}
 */
function getResponsiveBreakpoint() {
    var envs = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg"];
    var env = "";

    var $el = $("<div>");
    $el.appendTo($("body"));

    for (var i = envs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        env = envs[i];
        $el.addClass("d-" + env + "-none");;
        if ($el.is(":hidden")) {
            break; // env detected
        }
    }
    $el.remove();
    return env;
}
```

I think it would be useful, as it's easy to integrate to any project. It uses native [responsive display classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements) of the Bootstrap itself.

Answer (score 13):

You could use the window size and hard code the breakpoints. Using Angular:

```
angular
    .module('components.responsiveDetection', [])
    .factory('ResponsiveDetection', function ($window) {
        return {
            getBreakpoint: function () {
                var w = $window.innerWidth;
                if (w < 768) {
                    return 'xs';
                } else if (w < 992) {
                    return 'sm';
                } else if (w < 1200) {
                    return 'md';
                } else {
                    return 'lg';
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: I like this answer. No other libraries (not even jQuery) required.

Answer (score 11):

Have you taken a look at Response.js? It's designed for this kind of thing. Combine Response.band and Response.resize.

http://responsejs.com/

```
Response.resize(function() {
    if ( Response.band(1200) )
    {
       // 1200+
    }    
    else if ( Response.band(992) )
    {
        // 992+
    }
    else if ( Response.band(768) )
    {
        // 768+
    }
    else 
    {
        // 0->768
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting library, although it was not designed with Twitter Bootstrap 3 in mind. Anyway, looks like it can be easily adapted into TWBS3.

Answer (score 5):

Using this approach with [Response.js](http://responsejs.com/) is better. Response.resize triggers on every window resize where crossover will only be triggered if breakpoint is changed

```
Response.create({
    prop : "width",
    breakpoints : [1200, 992, 768, 480, 320, 0]
});

Response.crossover('width', function() {
    if (Response.band(1200)) {
        // 1200+

    } else if (Response.band(992)) {
        // 992+

    } else if (Response.band(768)) {
        // 768+

    } else if (Response.band(480)) {
        //480+

    } else {
        // 0->320

    }
});

Response.ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

There should be no problem with some manual implementation like the one mentioned by @oozic.

Here are a couple of libs you could take a look at:

- [Response.js](http://responsejs.com/) - jQuery plugin - make use of html data attributes and also has a js api.
- [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) - enquire.js is a lightweight, pure JavaScript library for responding to CSS media queries
- [SimpleStateManager](https://github.com/jonathan-fielding/SimpleStateManager) - s a javascript state manager for responsive websites. It is built to be light weight, has no dependencies.

Note that these libs are designed to work independently of bootstrap, foundation, etc. You can configure your own breakpoints and have fun.

Comment: Enquire.js looks promising.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to add this to your bootstrap project to check active breakpoint visually

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var mode;

            $('<div class="mode-informer label-info" style="z-index:1000;position: fixed;bottom:10px;left:10px">%mode%</div>').appendTo('body');


            var checkMode = function () {

                if ($(window).width() < 768) {
                    return 'xs';
                }
                else if ($(window).width() >= 768 && $(window).width() < 992) {
                    return 'sm';
                }
                else if ($(window).width() >= 992 && $(window).width() < 1200) {
                    return 'md';
                }
                else {
                    return 'lg';
                }
            };

            var compareMode = function () {
                if (mode !== checkMode()) {
                    mode = checkMode();

                    $('.mode-informer').text(mode).animate({
                        bottom: '100'
                    }, 100, function () {
                        $('.mode-informer').animate({bottom: 10}, 100)
                    });
                }
            };

            $(window).on('resize', function () {
                compareMode()
            });

            compareMode();

        });

    </script>
```

Here is the [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/102795)

Answer (score 4):

Building on Maciej Gurban's answer (which is fantastic... if you like this, please just up vote his answer). If you're building a service to query you can return the currently active service with the setup below. This could replace other breakpoint detection libraries entirely (like enquire.js if you put in some events). *Note that I've added a container with an ID to the DOM elements to speed up DOM traversal.*

HTML

```
<div id="detect-breakpoints">
    <div class="breakpoint device-xs visible-xs"></div>
    <div class="breakpoint device-sm visible-sm"></div>
    <div class="breakpoint device-md visible-md"></div>
    <div class="breakpoint device-lg visible-lg"></div>
</div>
```

COFFEESCRIPT (AngularJS, but this is easily convertible)

```
# this simple service allows us to query for the currently active breakpoint of our responsive app
myModule = angular.module('module').factory 'BreakpointService', ($log) ->

  # alias could be: xs, sm, md, lg or any over breakpoint grid prefix from Bootstrap 3
  isBreakpoint: (alias) ->
    return $('#detect-breakpoints .device-' + alias).is(':visible')

  # returns xs, sm, md, or lg
  getBreakpoint: ->
    currentBreakpoint = undefined
    $visibleElement = $('#detect-breakpoints .breakpoint:visible')
    breakpointStringsArray = [['device-xs', 'xs'], ['device-sm', 'sm'], ['device-md', 'md'], ['device-lg', 'lg']]
    # note: _. is the lodash library
    _.each breakpointStringsArray, (breakpoint) ->
      if $visibleElement.hasClass(breakpoint[0])
        currentBreakpoint = breakpoint[1]
    return currentBreakpoint
```

JAVASCRIPT (AngularJS)

```
var myModule;

myModule = angular.module('modules').factory('BreakpointService', function($log) {
  return {
    isBreakpoint: function(alias) {
      return $('#detect-breakpoints .device-' + alias).is(':visible');
    },
    getBreakpoint: function() {
      var $visibleElement, breakpointStringsArray, currentBreakpoint;
      currentBreakpoint = void 0;
      $visibleElement = $('#detect-breakpoints .breakpoint:visible');
      breakpointStringsArray = [['device-xs', 'xs'], ['device-sm', 'sm'], ['device-md', 'md'], ['device-lg', 'lg']];
      _.each(breakpointStringsArray, function(breakpoint) {
        if ($visibleElement.hasClass(breakpoint[0])) {
          currentBreakpoint = breakpoint[1];
        }
      });
      return currentBreakpoint;
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using $(document).width(), you should get set a CSS rule that gives you this information.

I just wrote an article to get it accurately. See it here : http://www.xurei-design.be/2013/10/how-to-accurately-detect-responsive-breakpoints/

Comment: This is the best approach in my point of view as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22885503/439427

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use jQuery to detect the current css width of the bootstrap container class?

ie..

```
if( parseInt($('#container').css('width')) > 1200 ){
  // do something for desktop screens
}
```

You could also use $(window).resize() to prevent your layout from "soiling the bed" if someone resizes the browser window.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of inserting the below many times into each page...

```
<div class="device-xs visible-xs"></div>
<div class="device-sm visible-sm"></div>
<div class="device-md visible-md"></div>
<div class="device-lg visible-lg"></div>
```

Just use JavaScript to dynamically insert it into every page (note that I have updated it to work with Bootstrap 3 with `.visible-*-block`:

```
// Make it easy to detect screen sizes
var bootstrapSizes = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg"];
for (var i = 0; i < bootstrapSizes.length; i++) {
    $("<div />", {
        class: 'device-' + bootstrapSizes[i] + ' visible-' + bootstrapSizes[i] + '-block'
    }).appendTo("body");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment but for those who are having problems with getting "unrecognized" when they try using Maciej Gurban's ResponsiveToolKit,  I was also getting that error until I noticed that Maciej actually references the toolkit from the bottom of the page in his CodePen

I tried doing that and suddenly it worked !  So, use the ResponsiveToolkit but put your links in the bottom of the page:

I don't know why it makes a difference but it does.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to detect the current viewport **without** putting the viewport size numbers in your javascript.

See css and javascript snippets here:  https://gist.github.com/steveh80/288a9a8bd4c3de16d799

After adding that snippets to your css and javascript files you can detect the current viewport like this:

```
viewport.is('xs') // returns boolean
```

If you want to detect a viewport range use it like this

```
viewport.isEqualOrGreaterThan('sm') // returns true for sm, md and lg
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap's CSS for the `.container` class looks like that:

```
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        width: 750px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        width: 970px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        width: 1170px;
    }
}
```

So this means we can safely rely on `jQuery('.container').css('width')` to detect breakpoints without the drawbacks of relying on `jQuery(window).width()`.

We can write a function like this:

```
function detectBreakpoint() {
    // Let's ensure we have at least 1 container in our pages.
    if (jQuery('.container').length == 0) {
        jQuery('body').append('<div class="container"></div>');
    }

    var cssWidth = jQuery('.container').css('width');

    if (cssWidth === '1170px') return 'lg';
    else if (cssWidth === '970px') return 'md';
    else if (cssWidth === '750px') return 'sm';

    return 'xs';
}
```

And then test it like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        jQuery('p').html('current breakpoint is: ' + detectBreakpoint());
    });

    detectBreakpoint();
});
```

Comment: This will only work at the specified widths; anything in between will fail. It might be best to:

First, parseInt on  cssWidth 
`var cssWidth = parseInt( jQuery('.container').css('width') );`

Second, use ranges 
`if ( cssWidth < 768) {
            return 'xs';
        }
        else if (cssWidth >= 768 &&  cssWidth <= 992) {
             return 'sm';
        }
        else if (cssWidth > 992 &&  cssWidth <= 1200) {
            return 'md';
        }
        else  {
            return 'lg';
        }`

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS `:before` and `content` property to print the breakpoint state in the `<span id="breakpoint-js">` so the JavaScript just have to read this data to turn it as a variable to use within your function.

(run the snippet to see the example)

NOTE: *I added a few line of CSS to use the `<span>` as a red flag in the upper corner of my browser. Just make sure to switch it back to `display:none;` before pushing your stuff public.*

```js
// initialize it with jquery when DOM is ready
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    getBootstrapBreakpoint();
});

// get bootstrap grid breakpoints
var theBreakpoint = 'xs'; // bootstrap336 default = mobile first
function getBootstrapBreakpoint(){
   theBreakpoint = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#breakpoint-js'),':before').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/['"]+/g, '');
   console.log('bootstrap grid breakpoint = ' + theBreakpoint);
}
```

```css
#breakpoint-js {
  /* display: none; //comment this while developping. Switch back to display:NONE before commit */
  /* optional red flag layout */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: .7;
  /* end of optional red flag layout */
}
#breakpoint-js:before {
  content: 'xs'; /* default = mobile first */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #breakpoint-js:before {
    content: 'sm';
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  #breakpoint-js:before {
    content: 'md';
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #breakpoint-js:before {
    content: 'lg';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <span id="breakpoint-js"></span>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Bootstrap grid examples</h1>
    <p class="lead">Basic grid layouts to get you familiar with building within the Bootstrap grid system.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap4 with jQuery, simplified solution**

```
<div class="device-sm d-sm-none"></div>
<div class="device-md d-md-none"></div>
<div class="device-lg d-lg-none"></div>
<div class="device-xl d-xl-none"></div>
<script>
var size = $('.device-xl').is(':hidden') ? 'xl' : ($('.device-lg').is(':hidden') ? 'lg'
    : ($('.device-md').is(':hidden') ? 'md': ($('.device-sm').is(':hidden') ? 'sm' : 'xs')));
alert(size);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution (Bootstrap 4):

```
<div class="alert alert-warning row">
    <div class="col">
        Bootstrap breakpoint is
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="d-block d-sm-none">
            XS
        </div>
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">
            SM
        </div>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">
            MD
        </div>
        <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">
            LG
        </div>
        <div class="d-none d-xl-block">
            XL
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a very neat solution I've used before and works great, you just have to adjust LG and XL tags, we'll blame Ctrl + C & Ctrl + V for that.

Comment: I can't there are too many pending edits, you just need to display the correct breakpoint, you display MD for the last 3 (md, lg, xl).

Answer (score 1):

I've made a native jQuery method for Twitter Bootstrap screen size detection. Here is:

```
// Screen size ID will be stored in this variable (global var for JS)
var CurrentBootstrapScreenSize = 'unknown';

$(document).ready(function () {

    // <div> objects for all screen sizes required for screen size detection.
    // These <div> is hidden for users eyes.
    var currentScreenSizeDetectorObjects = $('<div>').css({
            'position':'absolute',
            'top':'-200px'
        }).addClass('current-screen-size').append([
            $('<div>').addClass('device-xs visible-xs').html('&nbsp;'),
            $('<div>').addClass('device-sm visible-sm').html('&nbsp;'),
            $('<div>').addClass('device-md visible-md').html('&nbsp;'),
            $('<div>').addClass('device-lg visible-lg').html('&nbsp;')
        ]);

    // Attach <div> objects to <body>
    $('body').prepend(currentScreenSizeDetectorObjects);

    // Core method for detector
    function currentScreenSizeDetectorMethod() {
        $(currentScreenSizeDetectorObjects).find('div').each(function() {
            var className = $(this).attr('class');
            if($(this).is(':visible')) {
                if(String(className).match(/device-xs/)) CurrentBootstrapScreenSize = 'xs';
                else if(String(className).match(/device-sm/)) CurrentBootstrapScreenSize = 'sm';
                else if(String(className).match(/device-md/)) CurrentBootstrapScreenSize = 'md';
                else if(String(className).match(/device-lg/)) CurrentBootstrapScreenSize = 'lg';
                else CurrentBootstrapScreenSize = 'unknown';
            };
        })
        console.log('Current Bootstrap screen size is: '+CurrentBootstrapScreenSize);
        $('.CurrentBootstrapScreenSize').first().html('Bootstrap current screen size: <b>' + CurrentBootstrapScreenSize + '</b>' );
    }

    // Bind screen size and orientation change
    $(window).bind("resize orientationchange", function() {
        // Execute screen detection
        currentScreenSizeDetectorMethod();
    });

    // Execute screen detection on page initialize
    currentScreenSizeDetectorMethod();

});
```

JSFillde: https://jsfiddle.net/pstepniewski/7dz6ubus/

JSFillde as fullscreen example: https://jsfiddle.net/pstepniewski/7dz6ubus/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in this, i wrote a breakpoint detection based on CSS breakpoints using TypeScript and Observables. it is not very hard to make ES6 out of it, if you remove the types. In my example i use Sass, but it is also easy to remove this.

Here is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/StefanJelner/dorj184g/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.7/Rx.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

SCSS:

```
body::before {
  content: 'xs';
  display: none;

  @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    content: 's';
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    content: 'm';
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    content: 'l';
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    content: 'xl';
  }
}
```

TypeScript:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

class BreakpointChangeService {
    private breakpointChange$: BehaviorSubject<string>;

    constructor(): BehaviorSubject<string> {
        // initialize BehaviorSubject with the current content of the ::before pseudo element
        this.breakpointChange$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(this.getBreakpoint());

        // observe the window resize event, throttle it and combine it with the BehaviorSubject
        Rx.Observable
            .fromEvent(window, 'resize')
            .throttleTime(0, Rx.Scheduler.animationFrame)
            .withLatestFrom(this.breakpointChange$)
            .subscribe(this.update.bind(this))
        ;

        return this.breakpointChange$;
    }

    // method to get the content of the ::before pseudo element
    private getBreakpoint(): string {
        // see https://www.lullabot.com/articles/importing-css-breakpoints-into-javascript
        return window.getComputedStyle(document.body, ':before').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/[\"\']/g, '');
    }

    private update(_, recent): void {
        var current = this.getBreakpoint();
        if(recent !== current) { this.breakpointChange$.next(current); }
    }
}

// if the breakpoint changes, react on it
var $result = document.getElementById('result');
new BreakpointChangeService().subscribe(breakpoint => {
    $result.innerHTML = Date.now()+': '+breakpoint;
});
```

I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

I was not really satisfied with the given answers, which seem overly complicated to use to me, so I wrote my own solution. However, for the time being this relies on underscore/lodash to work.

https://github.com/LeShrimp/GridSizeEvents

You can use it like this:

```
GridSizeEvents.addListener(function (newSize, oldSize) {
    // Will output eg. "xs -> sm"
    console.log(oldSize + ' -> ' + newSize);
});
```

This works out of the Box for Bootstrap 3, as the breakpoints are hard coded to 768px, 992px and 1200px. For other versions you could easily adapt the code.

Internally this uses [matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) and should thus guarantee to produce results that are in synch with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it'll help some of you, but there is a plugin which help you to detect on which current Bootstrap **v4** breakpoint you are see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs-breakpoints

Simple to use (can be used with or without jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  bsBreakpoints.init()
  console.warn(bsBreakpoint.getCurrentBreakpoint())

  $(window).on('new.bs.breakpoint', function (event) {
    console.warn(event.breakpoint)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

*For anyone using **knockout.js***, I wanted some [knockout.js observable properties](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) that would tell me when the breakpoints are hit.  I opted to use [Modernizr's support for css-style media queries](https://modernizr.com/docs) so the numbers matched the bootstrap definitions, and to get modernizr's compatibility benefits.  My knockout view model is as follows:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    // depends on jquery, Modernizr
    var self = this;
    self.widthXsOrLess = ko.observable();
    self.widthSmOrLess = ko.observable();
    self.widthMdOrLess = ko.observable();
    var setWindowSizeVars = function() {
        self.widthXsOrLess(!Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 768px)'));
        self.widthSmOrLess(!Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 992px)'));
        self.widthMdOrLess(!Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 1200px)'));
    };
    $(window).resize(setWindowSizeVars);
    setWindowSizeVars();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is good way to detect it (maybe funny, but works) and You can use necessary element so code is clear:

**Example:**
css:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #someElement
    {
         background: pink
    }
}
```

and in document by jQuery:

```
if($('#someElement').css('background') == 'pink')
{
    doWhatYouNeed();
}
```

of course css property is any.

Answer (score 0):

Since bootstrap 4 will be out soon I thought I would share a function that supports it (xl is now a thing) and performs minimal jQuery to get the job done.

```
/**
 * Get the Bootstrap device size
 * @returns {string|boolean} xs|sm|md|lg|xl on success, otherwise false if Bootstrap is not working or installed
 */
function findBootstrapEnvironment() {
    var environments = ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl'];
    var $el = $('<span />');
    $el.appendTo($('body'));
    for (var i = environments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var env = environments[i];
        $el.addClass('hidden-'+env);
        if ($el.is(':hidden')) {
            $el.remove();
            return env;
        }
    }
    $el.remove();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4

```js
setResponsiveDivs();

function setResponsiveDivs() {
    var data = [
        {id: 'visible-xs', class: 'd-block d-sm-none'},
        {id: 'visible-sm', class: 'd-none d-sm-block d-md-none'},
        {id: 'visible-md', class: 'd-none d-md-block d-lg-none'},
        {id: 'visible-lg', class: 'd-none d-lg-block d-xl-none'},
        {id: 'visible-xl', class: 'd-none d-xl-block'}
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.setAttribute('id', data[i].id);
        el.setAttribute('class', data[i].class);
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(el);
    }
}

function isVisible(type) {
    return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('visible-' + type), null).getPropertyValue('display') === 'block';
}

// then, at some point
window.onresize = function() {
    console.log(isVisible('xs') === true ? 'xs' : '');
    console.log(isVisible('sm') === true ? 'sm' : '');
    console.log(isVisible('md') === true ? 'md' : '');
    console.log(isVisible('lg') === true ? 'lg' : '');
    console.log(isVisible('xl') === true ? 'xl' : '');
};
```

or minified

```js
function setResponsiveDivs(){for(var e=[{id:"visible-xs","class":"d-block d-sm-none"},{id:"visible-sm","class":"d-none d-sm-block d-md-none"},{id:"visible-md","class":"d-none d-md-block d-lg-none"},{id:"visible-lg","class":"d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none"},{id:"visible-xl","class":"d-none d-xl-block"}],s=0;s<e.length;s++){var l=document.createElement("div");l.setAttribute("id",e[s].id),l.setAttribute("class",e[s]["class"]),document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(l)}}function isVisible(e){return"block"===window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("visible-"+e),null).getPropertyValue("display")}setResponsiveDivs();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Knockout**, then you could use the following custom binding to bind the current viewport breakpoint (xs, sm, md or lg) to an observable in your model. The binding...

- wraps the 4 `divs` with `visible-??` class in a div with id `detect-viewport` and adds it to the body if it doesn't exist already (so you could reuse this binding without duplicating these divs)
- sets the current viewport breakpoint to the bound observable by querying which of the divs is visible
- updates the current viewport breakpoint when the window is resized

```js
ko.bindingHandlers['viewport'] = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        if (!document.getElementById('detect-viewport')) {
            let detectViewportWrapper = document.createElement('div');
            detectViewportWrapper.id = 'detect-viewport';
            
            ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg"].forEach(function(breakpoint) {
                let breakpointDiv = document.createElement('div');
                breakpointDiv.className = 'visible-' + breakpoint;
                detectViewportWrapper.appendChild(breakpointDiv);
            });

            document.body.appendChild(detectViewportWrapper);
        }

        let setCurrentBreakpoint = function() {
            valueAccessor()($('#detect-viewport div:visible')[0].className.substring('visible-'.length));
        }
      
        $(window).resize(setCurrentBreakpoint);
        setCurrentBreakpoint();
    }
};

ko.applyBindings({
  currentViewPort: ko.observable()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div data-bind="viewport: currentViewPort"></div>
<div>    
    Current viewport breakpoint: <strong data-bind="text: currentViewPort"></strong>
</div>
<div>
    (Click the <em>full page</em> link of this snippet to test the binding with different window sizes)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the OP, but here's my solution for this using Bootstrap 3. In my use case, I was only targeting rows, but the same could be applied to the container, etc.

Just change .row to whatever you want.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var alterClass = function () {

        var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

        if (ww < 768) {

            $('.row').addClass('is-xs').removeClass('is-sm').removeClass('is-lg').removeClass('is-md');

        } else if (ww >= 768 && ww < 992) {

            $('.row').addClass('is-sm').removeClass('is-xs').removeClass('is-lg').removeClass('is-md');

        } else if (ww >= 992 && ww < 1200) {

            $('.row').addClass('is-md').removeClass('is-xs').removeClass('is-lg').removeClass('is-sm');

        } else if (ww >= 1200) {

            $('.row').addClass('is-lg').removeClass('is-md').removeClass('is-sm').removeClass('is-xs');

        };
    };

    // Make Changes when the window is resized
    $(window).resize(function () {
        alterClass();
    });

    // Fire when the page first loads
    alterClass();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea how to do it using CSS variables.
For Bootstrap 3 (or Bootstrap 4) using CSS:

```
:root {
    --current-breakpoint: xs;
}
@media (min-width: 576px){
  :root {
    --current-breakpoint: sm;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
  :root {
    --current-breakpoint: md;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  :root {
    --current-breakpoint: lg;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
  :root {
    --current-breakpoint: xl;
  }
}
```

Bootstrap 4 and SCSS may look like this:

```
:root{
  @include media-breakpoint-up(xs) {
    --current-breakpoint:xs;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
    --current-breakpoint:sm;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    --current-breakpoint:md;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-up(lg)  {
    --current-breakpoint:lg;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-up(xl)  {
    --current-breakpoint:xl;
  }
}
```

The JS code may be:

```
window.onresize=()=>{
     console.log(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--current-breakpoint'));
}
```