# Bootstrap 3 layout design

Tags: layout, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make a layout shown in this image

[image]

I could have done it easily with grid system but I want the first post's description off the grid system or below the both column. However, for mobile devices I want it to appear with the image or in the same grid like the image below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't expect you can do this with Bootstrap's CSS only cause the order of your elements change from desktop to mobile.

Try this html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color:red;">1</div>

    <div class="rightblock col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:lightgreen;">3</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:lightyellow;">4</div> 
        </div>
    </div> 
           <div class="clearfix visible-md visible-lg"></div>    
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 lefttext" style="background-color:lightblue;">2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Where 2 = the caption of your first item (1) and 3 and 4 are your second and third item.

For the mobile version use javascript to swap 2 (.lefttext) and the 3/4 block (.rightblock):

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        $(".rightblock").insertAfter($(".lefttext"));
    } 
});
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/94560

**Note 1**: `$(window).resize` only will called on a real resize (from big to small) and not when opening the small screen direct. See here for better solution to react on screen size changes:  [How to detect responsive breakpoints of Twitter Bootstrap 3 using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575582/how-to-detect-responsive-breakpoints-of-twitter-bootstrap-3-using-javascript)

**Note 2**: see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets for explanation of the `clearfix`