# See current column category used in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, console.log

Is there a fast easy way to query the console for the column category (xs sm md lg) used in the current viewport size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I wrote a simple function for this, seems there is no native way to do this.

```
function bootstrapSize() {
    switch(true) {
        case window.innerWidth > 1200: return 'lg';
        case window.innerWidth > 992: return 'md';
        case window.innerWidth > 768: return 'sm';
        default: return 'xs';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do this from the console, but you might use the technique described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22885503/65971 to create your code snippet to query this from the console.

For each breakpoint it creates a `<div>` for example `<div class="visible-xs-block" />` on which it tests if it's visible.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using  hasClass() ?

http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/