# Binding to or watching viewport changes in angular

Tags: angularjs

I would like to have a `ng-if` evaluate a viewpoint.

For example

```
<div ng-if="viewPort=='SM'">
```

Or, maybe just a `$watch` and then I can set a variable that's in the `$scope`

I know I could do some magic with events etc, but I am looking for the angler way if one exists.

**EDIT**

Thinking about how this would work, I presume I would need a service and a way to hook into viewport changes so my controller can update the model so the view can react.

Comment: ng-if does exist in angular.Are you asking about ng-if or am I getting your question wrong?

Comment: I would like to be able to evaluate the bootstrap viewPort, I could probs code it all up but it would be nice if someone had used a trusted open source module before.

Comment: May be you have already seen this post. I think it does what you are looking for (or something close enough) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575582/how-to-detect-responsive-breakpoints-of-twitter-bootstrap-3-using-javascript

Comment: that is useful, but I would love a service that just did all that.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-if` automatically evaluates the expression inside as it creates a watcher. You don't need any module, any 3rd party .... anything basically. That's just plain 2-way data binding. In your controller just do:

```
$scope.viewport='';
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.viewport='SM'
}, 5000);
```

After 5 seconds you will see your div appearing. Just mind that you'll need to inject both $scope and $timeout.

Comment: yep, I understand but I need something that does something when the viewport changes, as in http://codepen.io/dih/full/ivECj (that's from the example in the comment on the Q) but i think a service would wrap it up better.

Comment: I understand what you mean. There isn't anything like that in the core Angular however I would suggest you to create a directive and use the  window.resize event to know when the size changes.