# Re-order blocks in Bootstrap Layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm really stuck with a layout problem on my website.

I have the web-screen view laid out the way I want, but need to shuffle the order of the block a little for mobile view. I've tried using the align classes, and the 'push' or 'pull' classes, but can't what I need.

Here is the laptop view I need:

Block 1  and Block 2 in a column on the left,
Block3, Block4, Block5, Block6 and Block7 on the right.

This I can do no problem.

But then for the mobile view, I need it in this order from top to bottom (see images below):

Block 3
Block 1
Block 5
Block 4
Block 2
Block 5
Block 6

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Just realised that because I"m new in here, I can't post images...  Hopefully my description makes sense...

Comment: Could you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Just put the minimal code in it, something we can work with.

Comment: Can you add a link to an image?

Comment: Where did `Block 7` go in the mobile view? Or is that to be hidden? Yea. A demo fiddle would help alot.

Comment: Just to check: what browser(s) are you testing with (based on personal experience that IE in compatibility mode and twitter-bootstrap tend to puke on each other when trying to use push/pull)

Comment: If what you are trying to do is not possible then you can always make 2 grids, one for mobiles and one for desktops, both of which will be appropriately hidden.

Comment: Have you looked at offsetting columns in the Bootstrap CSS docs?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use jQuery to achieve this.

You can have 2 `<div>` tags.
One for the sidebar (`<div id="sidebar">`)
One for the main content (`<div id="main">`)
And one for the blocks (`<div id="blocks"`) (Each block would also have its own ID e.g. b1 for block 1)

Then you can arrange the blocks appropriately depending on the device using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b1").appendTo("#sidebar");
});
```

When it comes to detecting the device using Bootstraps breakpoints you can follow this tutorial: [How to detect responsive breakpoints of Twitter Bootstrap 3 using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575582/how-to-detect-responsive-breakpoints-of-twitter-bootstrap-3-using-javascript)

Comment: Here is a link to the page in question on my site. http://canvascut.com/sets/Axe Thanks all for your help!