# Change size of bootstrap-toggle according to media dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to make all my bootstrap toggles of `mini` size if the page size < 768px and back to normal again once it is more than that. For all other controls I'm using `@media (max-width: 768px) {` css, but I could not figure out what styles to add to make bootstrap toggle `mini` size.

One of other approaches I tried is:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $("[data-toggle='toggle']").bootstrapToggle({size: "mini"});
        }

    }, true);
```

But that reinitializes all bootstrap toggles, removing all the setup made with data- attributes. I would also prefer css approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Bootstrap provides a lot of useful utilities for you to use in response to screen sizes, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575582/how-to-detect-responsive-breakpoints-of-twitter-bootstrap-3-using-javascript) for more info. Using this approach will probably be way better in the long run.

Secondly, you will want to give a specific CSS class or ID to any toggles that you want to target with your resize. `$("[data-toggle='toggle']")` Will select any element that matches the form:
`<tag data-toggle='toggle'>` and that probably means all toggles on your page.

So setting the toggle to like `<input data-toggle="toggle" class="resize">` and using `$('.resize').bootstrapToggle()` should help

Comment: Specific CSS class was one of the problems. The other one - I need to clear bootstrapToggle with `$(".mytoggle").bootstrapToggle('destroy');` before setting `$(".mytoggle").bootstrapToggle({size: "mini"})` But I can count this as an answer as this partially answers the question