# Open accordeon pane in Materialize CSS based on screensize

Tags: css, materialize

In materialize CSS, I can open a pane by adding a class `active` to the one I want opened. Is there also a way to let this be dependent of the current grid breakpoint? For instance using something like `active-lg`?

Otherwise, is there an option through javascript to get the current breakpoint (S/M/L/XL) from materialize CSS?

Comment: I don't know about `active`, but you could definitely do it through Javascript. check the many answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575582

Comment: Any idea if materialize CSS offers a method for determining the current breakpoint?

Comment: nope, no idea. I think such feature is probably not there in Materialize.