# Bootstrap - Get current screen mode

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to get the current screen mode without having to code a function which works with media queries?

e.g. I have a `container-fluid` div with class `chartContainer`.

```
.chartContainer {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 120px;
    padding-right: 120px;
}
```

But I only need the class `chartContainer` if the screen size is not `xs` or `sm`.

Are there bootstrap methods to find this out, without having to code own functions?

e.g. I would do something like this, which is quick and dirty but should work if the window size changes:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (BOOTSTRAP_CURRENT_SCREEN_MODE == 'xs' || BOOTSTRAP_CURRENT_SCREEN_MODE == 'sm') {
        $(".container-fluid").removeClass("chartContainer");
    } else {
        $(".container-fluid").addClass("chartContainer");
    }
},100);
```

Is there something like `BOOTSTRAP_CURRENT_SCREEN_MODE`?
How would I achieve my goal the best way?

Comment: Use css media-queries

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575582/how-to-detect-responsive-breakpoints-of-twitter-bootstrap-3-using-javascript

Comment: I already told that I try to not use media queries in my first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Media queries are the easiest way to do this.

```css
/* col-md-* and col-lg-* */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .chartContainer {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 120px;
    padding-right: 120px;
  }
}


/* col-xs-* and col-sm-* */

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .chartContainer {
    /* some other measurements here */
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="chartContainer">...</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I think this is the best way and javascript solutions would be dirty and inefficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get bootstrap's breakpoints in JS , use this :

```
var lg = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--breakpoint-lg');
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: "+lg+")").matches) {
  /* do something */
}
```

repeat that for the other breakpoints and tweak it to your needs,

here's a list of the [Availbale variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#css-variables) ( custom properties )

Media queries would be better , you can use it like :

`@media (min-width: var(--breakpoint-lg) ) { ...`