# How to detect if the site is loaded inside an iframe on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

The website I'm developing recently uses [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) framework. There is no problem about responsiveness while directly visiting the site.

There is another domain name (**domainB**) and I'm using URL embed method and it loads the actual site.

While visiting the domainB on a **mobile** device, the responsiveness doesn't work, it loads the **desktop** site not the mobile-size one.

So, my question:

### How to detect if the site is loaded inside an iframe on a mobile device?

I saw [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t) question and by that method it can be understood if the webpage is being loaded inside an iframe but how to detect if the visitor is on a **mobile device**?

---

*(I don't have any code control on domainB, the URL embed feature is served by domain name registrar company.)*

*(There could be some SEO issues about this, I know this.)*

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mdetect.js script from [MobileESP](https://github.com/ahand/mobileesp/blob/master/JavaScript/mdetect.js) to check if the page is loaded on a mobile device. The method `DetectMobileQuick()` seems to do what you want, you can find an example [here](https://github.com/lucanos/mdetect/blob/master/demo/javascript.htm) . As described on the MobileESP page, this approach may not work for older phones, including older BlackBerry, PalmOS, and Windows Mobile devices, that have poor support for Javascript. You may also want to check out this post that describes how you can use bootstrap to determine the size of the device view being used.

[How to detect which device view you're on using Twitter Bootstrap API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441456/how-to-detect-which-device-view-youre-on-using-twitter-bootstrap-api)