# Do not Render particular Element in Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I am working on ASP.Net 4.5

I have a control which I don't want to load or do not want to render the elements for mobile view,
Below code is working fine,
But the problem is it is loading the control and hiding it, which I don't wan , Can I avoid loading of my control in mobile view?

Below is my aspx Page

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    <CC2:MegaMenu ID="MegaMenu1" runat="server" ></CC2:MegaMenu>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any flag or any other way to know in server side if you're in *mobile mode* or not ?

Comment: No i dont have that only by bootstrap visble xs class i used

Comment: As a quick suggestion, I would tell you to use something to check if user is actually using a mobile device([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15150381/1267304)), like in the login for example, and store it in a key on the session to rely on and use to make decisions as that one you're requesting.