# Make my self hosted webpage accessible to mobile phones only

Tags: android, mobile, web

I have these questions:

1. Can you make a web page accessible only by mobile application?
2. Limiting site access to Mobile Phones
3. Only show web page to mobile browsers

I'm creating a site that will only work if you have a smart phone, as it interacts with its features. I don't want to waste desktop searchers time therefore I would like to display a page saying "Only view-able via smart phones" if it detects a non smart phone visitor.  Its important that desktops viewers cannot go any further into the site, so the detection has to happen asap.

Comment: I have this so far: [http://detectmobilebrowsers.com] but im sure someone on here will be able to help further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if the device is a mobile device, this may have been answered, did you look at the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013778/a-check-in-javascript-that-returns-whether-i-am-on-a-smartphone)?

Comment: Just had a quick look, thank you very much, it looks like something that i can implement.  I can detect if the visitor is a phone and then hopefully redirect them to a page.