# Redirect According To Device - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular I am trying to redirect the page according to device. If it is **Web** I am redirecting `www.web.com` ,If it is **Andriod** I am redirecting to `www.andriod.com` and If it is **iOS**, I am redirecting to `www.iOS.com` But I don't know how to find the device and implement this condition.

**TS**

```
if(mobile.andriod){                                    //How to check whether it is Andriod
window.location.href='www.andriod.com'
}
else if(mobile.ios){                                  //How to check whether it is iOS
  window.location.href='www.ios.com'
}
else if(web){
   window.location.href='www.web.com'
}
```

Comment: Try [ngx-device-detector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-device-detector).

Comment: this can help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013778/a-check-in-javascript-that-returns-whether-i-am-on-a-smartphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){                                    
window.location.href='www.andriod.com'
}
else if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)){                                  
  window.location.href='www.ios.com'
}
else {
   window.location.href='www.web.com'
}
```