# Best way to redirect single php page for mobile devices with PHP/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP google map application that I want to make visible to users when they are using a desktop but redirect to another PHP page if the visitor is using a mobile device.  I know there are numerous ways to do this from OS to browser type detection but was wondering if someone could provide some code they feel is the best way to handle this and it being the most consistent?

Comment: use `window.location.href = "http://url-that-you-want.com"` (JS)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you don't want to use javascript, you can handle it via php.
Take a look at this lib: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/.
And then you could do something like:

```
<?php
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    header('Location: yourpage.php');
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Good lib by the way! a very useful one now-days!

Comment: Up voted because even today this library is very reliable and usable.

Comment: Perfect ! I have a solution !

Comment: How to detect if iPhone or Android?

Answer (score 7):

1. Some servers have **$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']** as not set, so make sure to check if empty first
2. Readability is important to us, so we are using this instead of others complex regex. Just **add other devices** as you see fit.

Here is the code we use:

```
<?php
if(! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if( preg_match('@(iPad|iPod|iPhone|Android|BlackBerry|SymbianOS|SCH-M\d+|Opera Mini|Windows CE|Nokia|SonyEricsson|webOS|PalmOS)@', $useragent) ){
        header('Location: ./mobile/');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want javascript or php solution? Using JS you can just check if there is 'Mobile' in UA:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mobile') > -1) location.href = 'your-mobile-page-url';
```

Comment: Not all mobile browser UA strings have the word "Mobile" in them.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823144/is-there-a-quintessential-mobile-user-agent-regexp-pattern

Comment: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html
Of course we are talking about phones that can actually use the application, right?

Comment: Yes. But this would show the actual app for phones which don't; which may not be what the OP wants. Also, I believe you meant `== -1` instead of `!= -1` in your answer.

Comment: And look at this monstrous regex used in http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/
Thats just not right.

Comment: Yes, a bit of an overkill for sure. But then it depends on how mobile-proof the OP wants it. The *best* imo would be to make the app compatible with mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using simple dimension conditions

```
if (screen.width < 600 || screen.height < 200) {
    window.location = 'anotherPage.html'
}
```

`screen` and `window` dimensions will be different if browser window minimized

Can use combination of window/screen tests and alert user to issues also and give them option to redirect

Comment: The latest iPad has a higher resolution than my Desktop PC ;-)

Comment: But he may want to add something special for mobile users, enlarge buttons, etc.

Comment: @Killah  I don't know what OP wants in his app..am simply trying to offer a potential solution other than browser sniffing

Answer (score 0):

Using the user-agent string

```
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
    header('Location: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');
```

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: And I was curious why most of the sites written in php just don't care about performance. Such a monstrous regex just to check if site is viewed from mobile? Think how it would behave under few thousands of users wanting to access the app.

Comment: detectmobilebrowsers.com is ok, but it doesn't match ipad in useragent when I try their latest regex version from their site. Use with caution

Answer (score 0):

Checking for devices:

```
function UserAgentRegCheck($regText)
{
    $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    return preg_match('@('.$regText.')@', $useragent);
}

function isIphone() {
    return UserAgentRegCheck('iPad|iPod|iPhone');
}

function isAndroid() {
    return UserAgentRegCheck('Android');
}

function isMobile(){
    return UserAgentRegCheck('iPad|iPod|iPhone|Android|BlackBerry|SymbianOS|SCH-M\d+|Opera Mini|Windows CE|Nokia|SonyEricsson|webOS|PalmOS');
}
```

Redirection code:

```
if(isIphone()) {
    header('Location: http://www.google.com.ua');
    exit();
}

if(isAndroid()) {
    header('Location: http://youtube.com');
    exit();
}
```