# Mobile Redirect Not Working[Tested On Multiple Mobile Devices]

Tags: php, redirect, mobile

Hey everyone I'm using a code I found in another question that says it was answered correctly and working. It's not working for me though and I have tried it out on multiple devices.

The full code can be found here(this is the code library): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/master/Mobile_Detect.php

The question is here: [Best way to redirect single php page for mobile devices with PHP/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109770/best-way-to-redirect-single-php-page-for-mobile-devices-with-php-javascript)

And my code is:

```
<?php require('includes/mobileRedirect.php'); ?>
<?php
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
    if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
 header('Location: http://m.jollyrogerpcs.com/');
 exit;
}
?>
```

The problem seems to be around the "header" area. If I replace the header with a echo('mobile'); it works, but no matter what I do I cannot seem to get mobile to redirect.

EDIT: Problem solved by moving the code before the DOCTYPE.

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I got these:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/jollyrogerpcs/public_html/index.php:3) in /home/jollyrogerpcs/public_html/includes/head.php on line 4

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/jollyrogerpcs/public_html/index.php:3) in /home/jollyrogerpcs/public_html/includes/head.php on line 5

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/jollyrogerpcs/public_html/index.php:3) in /home/jollyrogerpcs/public_html/includes/head.php on line 6

Comment: That is these lines:

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

Comment: The file that you're trying to redirect from has already sent output to the browser. Once that happens no redirect can take place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [header location not working in my php code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525251/header-location-not-working-in-my-php-code)

Comment: I moved it to before everything else(right after the doctype) and nothing still happens.

Comment: Put it in a file by itself and try it.

Comment: Nevermind I moved it to BEFORE the DOCTYPE and it works. Thanks Jay. You mentioning it already outputting made me think to move it there.

Answer (score 0):

Moved this code to before the DOCTYPE and it works like a charm.

```
<?php require('includes/mobileRedirect.php'); 
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
 if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
  header('Location: http://m.jollyrogerpcs.com/');
}
?>
```