# How to automatically detect OS and redirect

Tags: android, linux, windows

I have a web site. I want to make the main page **index.php** which detects if the OS the user is running is mobile and redirects to a mobile site. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109770/best-way-to-redirect-single-php-page-for-mobile-devices-with-php-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to redirect single php page for mobile devices with PHP/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109770/best-way-to-redirect-single-php-page-for-mobile-devices-with-php-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var device = navigator.userAgent
if (device.match(/Iphone/i)|| device.match(/Ipod/i)|| device.match(/Android/i)|| device.match(/J2ME/i)|| device.match(/BlackBerry/i)|| device.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)|| device.match(/Opera Mini/i)|| device.match(/IEMobile/i)|| device.match(/Mobile/i)|| device.match(/Windows Phone/i)|| device.match(/windows mobile/i)|| device.match(/windows ce/i)|| device.match(/webOS/i)|| device.match(/palm/i)|| device.match(/bada/i)|| device.match(/series60/i)|| device.match(/nokia/i)|| device.match(/symbian/i)|| device.match(/HTC/i))
{
window.location = "./mobile.php";
}
else
{
var page = "./desktop.php";         
top.location = page;
}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to consider the `user-agent` header. Here's a very complete write up:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent