# Redirect mobile users to a url specific via Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this code in my .htaccess (default of my PHP site) and would like to redirect my users when accessing by cell, for a specific URL.

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteRule ^ http://pipocaplayfm.com/new-releases%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you just copy the answer into the question? I think you may be misunderstanding how this site works; have you read through the [tour] and introduction pages in the [help]?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Check for mime types commonly accepted by mobile devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ http://m.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

for more info check this topic.

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/mobile-redirect

Or check this answer for php code to do this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109951/7387742

Comment: is that correct? (I edited the question with the code that I put along with yours) I do not have so much knowledge.
I put it like this, but it was not directed to that page that was configured.

I'm trying to just leave a different home page (in this case it would be http://pipocaplayfm.com/new-releases) when accessing the mobile.

Comment: @jhonatan santos, try the whole code instead of your code.

Comment: If I just use the suggested code it goes out of the air the site.